# Where is i create php.ini

Tags: phpmyadmin

Where is the php.ini file added

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 50M

Comment: A simple google search should find you an answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can check your file

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

then search it using browse file and search php.ini